# How do I webscrape data from a graph?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

What would the python code be to get the timeseries data from the graph titled "Advanced Research Risk Parity Index Performance"?

This is the link:
https://eqmindexes.com/risk-parity-index-summary/

I know these are the libraries I am just not sure how to decipher the webpage code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import scrapy
```

Comment: The data for that chart is not really in a very friendly format. If you are new to web scraping, I would suggest something a little simpler to get a handle on it first.

Answer (score 0):

try this, hope its help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# import js2xml
from datetime import datetime
base_url = 'https://eqmindexes.com/risk-parity-index-summary/'
r = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
all_scripts = soup.find_all('script')
script_7 = all_scripts[7].string
result = re.search(r"(?<=var data = )([^$]*);", script_7).group()[:-1]

result = json.loads(result)
for d in result:
    date = datetime.fromtimestamp(d[0]/1000)-timedelta(days=1)
    date = date.strftime('%A,%b %d, %Y ')
    print(f"{date}, {d[1]}")
```

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot! All the values are there! One thing I noticed was when the values printed, the dates were shifted one day. ie today's date would have yesterdays value

Comment: change to  date = datetime.fromtimestamp(d[0]/1000)

Comment: if help don't forget to accept/upvote this/any post. Welcome, after lot of try able to this answer.